# Cannot get my ReportViewer to display my SRSS report

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reporting-services

In order to render a report in my MVC application, I have to use a webpage and a ReportViewer control to connect to the report.
Of which I am new to both.
I have a report which I can run in BIDS which runs as expected.
I used the wizard to set up the ReportViewer on my webpage as follows;

```
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" ProcessingMode="Remote" 
    Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" InteractiveDeviceInfos="(Collection)" 
    WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt">
    <ServerReport ReportPath="/Report_SHP_EmployeeHistory/ReportFirst" 
        DisplayName="reportfirst" />
</rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

I am using localhost on my development machine and I am using SQL Server 2008, BIDS VS 3.5.

So why would this not work?
In Firebug the error message is 
NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://localhost:2063/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Viewing SSRS Reports in an ASP.net MVC Site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4137835/viewing-ssrs-reports-in-an-asp-net-mvc-site)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question I found I had to utilize the Reporting Services Configuration Manager (Start -> All Programs -> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 -> Configuration Tools -> Reporting Services Configuration Manager) and work through the settings there. The Report Viewer can now link to the report. That leaves me with some other issues, but I will ask that in my next question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put it in a web page, with a `<form runat="server"> </form>` tags wrapping it.  You also have to make web.config changes to register the control and add in the appropriate handlers.