# What is routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}")

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

What is `routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}")`

I cannot find any .axd file in my project, can I remove this route rule?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

.axd files don't exist physically. ASP.NET uses URLs with .axd extensions (ScriptResource.axd and WebResource.axd) internally, and they are handled by an HttpHandler.

Therefore, you should keep this rule, to prevent ASP.NET MVC from trying to handle the request instead of letting the dedicated HttpHandler do it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'd want people to be able to download the "axd files" on your site as they contain javascript and styles.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The reason for putting `IgnoreRoute` into the routing configuration of MVC is to ensure that MVC doesn't try to handle the request. This is because `.axd` endpoints need to be handled by another HTTP handler (a handler that is *not* part of MVC) in order to serve scripts.

Comment: Is this entirely unnecessary in .NET core? I have searched on Google for an hour or so and I can't find any references for what the equivalent steps would be, so I'm assuming it's simply not needed.

Answer (score 43):

**Some Background**

If you open up this file:

```
%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\version\Config\Web.config
```

you will find this within the file:

```
<add path="WebResource.axd"
     verb="GET"
     type="System.Web.Handlers.AssemblyResourceLoader"
     validate="True" />
```

That is basically telling the Asp.NET runtime: "Hey asp.net dude, if a request comes for WebResource.axd then use AssemblyResourceLoader to process the request."

Please do **note that *WebResource.axd* is NOT a file** but simply a map (if I may say) to `AssemblyResourceLoader`. It is the name under which the handler is registered. On my machine, I found the following .axd handlers:

```
<add path="eurl.axd" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" validate="True" />
<add path="trace.axd" verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TraceHandler" validate="True" />
<add path="WebResource.axd" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.AssemblyResourceLoader" validate="True" />
<add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd"
```

**Ok, so what does that handler do?**

The `AssemblyResourceLoader` knows how to look for embedded files within an assembly so it can serve it (send it to the client i.e. a browser). For example, in asp.net web forms, if you use the validation controls, they depend on some javascript to show the errors on the web page. However, that javascript is embedded in an assembly. The browser needs the javascript so you will see this in the html of the page:

```
<script src="/YourSite/WebResource.axd?d=fs7zUa...&amp;t=6342..." type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The `AssemblyResourceLoader` will find the assembly where the javascript is embedded using the information in the querystring and return the javascript.

---

**Back to the Question**

So to answer the question, what is:

> `routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}")`

That is telling the routing engine that we will not be processing those requests that match that route pattern. In other words, we will not process `.axd` requests. Why? Because MVC itself is an HttpHandler similar to `.axd` and `.aspx` and many other handlers that are in the web.config file. The MVC handler does not know how to process the request such as looking for embedded resources in an assembly-the `AssemblyResourceLoader` knows how to do that. MVC knows how to do, well everything it does which is beyond the scope of this question and answer.

Comment: This definitely absolutely certainly should be the accepted answer, plus one from me.

Comment: Finally, a clear explanation of what WebResource.axd actually does whilst also providing a clear answer to the question. Thank you

Answer (score 18):

The route with the pattern {resource}.axd/{*pathInfo} is included to prevent requests for the Web resource files such as WebResource.axd or ScriptResource.axd from being passed to a controller.

Read link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

> You can also specify that routing should not handle certain URL requests. You prevent routing from handling certain requests by defining a route and specifying that the [StopRoutingHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.stoproutinghandler%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) class should be used to handle that pattern. When a request is handled by a [StopRoutingHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.stoproutinghandler%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) object, the [StopRoutingHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.stoproutinghandler%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) object blocks any additional processing of the request as a route. Instead, the request is processed as an ASP.NET page, Web service, or other ASP.NET endpoint. You can use the [RouteCollection.Ignore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routecollection.ignore%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method (or [RouteCollectionExtensions.IgnoreRoute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.routecollectionextensions.ignoreroute%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for MVC applications) to create routes that use the [StopRoutingHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.stoproutinghandler%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) class.

Answer (score 7):

Take a look in the below link:
http://haacked.com/archive/2008/07/14/make-routing-ignore-requests-for-a-file-extension.aspx

Answer (score 7):

Those are not files (they don't exist on disk) - they are just names under which some HTTP handlers are registered.

Comment: most relevant answer i would say.