# Report Configuration error in Report viewer

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, reportviewer

### I am getting report viewer configuration error and httpHandlers missing error.  In application i have used other report viewers but they are working properly. I found solution of adding httpHandlers in web.config file. But I have already defined httpHandlers in system.web.

```
    <system.web>
<authorization>
  <allow users="*" />
</authorization>
<sessionState timeout="1440" mode="InProc" />
<httpHandlers>
  <add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" validate="false" />
</httpHandlers>

<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
    <add assembly="System.ServiceProcess, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
  </assemblies>
  <buildProviders>
    <add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
  </buildProviders>
</compilation>

<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
```

and also defined Handler like below

```
<system.webServer>
       <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

but i don't know why i am getting this error.
what is the solution for it?

Comment: try  your question related solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11419059/report-viewer-configuration-error-in-view-source-of-webpage

Comment: @DenishParvadia i used all solution from that link but those are not working