# strange icon of crash image ,appear in my report viewer

Tags: asp.net, .net, webforms, report-viewer2010

A strange icon appear in my report, and is very strange because I don't add images in that position

like that
http://www.underconsideration.com/brandnew/archives/google_broken_image_00_b_logo_detail.gif

and design mode there ain't nothing

My aplication is written in Asp.net(C#) framework 4.0 and report viewer of visual studio 2010

Comment: Screenshot of the image in the environment it's not supposed to be in? Also, you could try checking the rdlc file itself for the image tags being that it's just an XML file. If it isn't there, try checking your CSS.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I found the result in Stackoverflow itself. We need to add the following in css file

```
body:nth-of-type(1) img[src*="Blank.gif"]{display:none;}
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13498696/reportviewer-showing-images-below-line-object-just-on-chrome