# How can I use a ReportViewer control with Razor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, reporting-services

I've seen many people saying to use an iframe or a new page to display a ReportViewer control.  Is there a way to display the control inline with the rest of my page without using an iframe?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use a reportviewer control in an asp.net mvc 3 razor view?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6144513/how-can-i-use-a-reportviewer-control-in-an-asp-net-mvc-3-razor-view)

Comment: Wow - I definitely did not find that piece while searching myself.  The **ViewUserControl1.ascx** part of the accepted answer is exactly it.

Comment: Another related question [**Viewing SSRS Reports in an ASP.NET MVC Site**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27231670/1366033)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `.ascx` user controls as partial views with Razor if they inherit from `System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl`.

In this instance, you can create an `ASCX` that contains your `ReportViewer` control and the requisite `ScriptManager` in your `View\Controller` folder:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ReportViewerControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="MyApp.Views.Reports.ReportViewerControl" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="rsweb" Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" %>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptManager" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="false" />
    <rsweb:ReportViewer Width="100%" Height="100%" ID="reportViewer" runat="server" AsyncRendering="false" ProcessingMode="Remote"> 
        <ServerReport />
    </rsweb:ReportViewer> 
</div>
</form>
```

In the code-behind, make sure to include the following in the `Page_Init`; otherwise, you won't be able to use any options in the report view:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Required for report events to be handled properly.
    Context.Handler = Page;
}
```

You also want to make sure that your control inherits from `System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl`:

```
public partial class ReportViewerControl : ViewUserControl
```

To use this control, you would do something like this in your Razor page:

```
@Html.Partial("ReportViewerControl", Model)
```

You can then setup your ReportViewer in the `Page_Load` of the control as you normally would.  You will have access to an `object` named `Model`, which you can cast to the type of the model that you send in and then use:

```
ReportViewParameters model = (ReportViewParameters)Model;
```

Comment: It's looking great but I want to have my users get a report by some parameters. After clicking the button the report viewer button "View Report" I'm faced with the following exception: 

System.Web.Mvc.HttpAntiForgeryException: The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present.

Any idea how to resolve this problem?

Comment: The report viewer component is doing some AJAX callbacks.... I'm using Orchard and its securing the controller actions with Antiforgery attributes.  You can turn that off in Orchard, but you then just have to set the Antiforgery attribute on specific controllers\actions that you want it to be on.

Comment: Everybody...make sure you include AsyncRendering="false" !!