# How can I have an ASP Web Form (ASPX) with a Razor MVC Layout?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, webforms

I have spent considerable time investigating having an ASP Web Form (ASPX) with a Razor MVC Layout, but have yet to make progress. I need this functionality since Webforms are faster to develop in, and I need to use the WebForm AjaxToolkit. I don't care about passing it a Controller or Model because I can handle all that in the code behind.

It seems to boil down to these options:

1. **ASP Master Page that builds a Razor Page**

   I based this answer on http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/a-webform-view-with-a-razor-layout-in-asp-net-mvc-3 - unfortunatly I never got this to work. The problem I had was that in the Master ASP file, there's no link to a controller or model, so calling

   ```xml
   <%=Html.Partial('Page.cshtml')%>
   ```

   from the ASP Master page results in a null exception, because the read-only "Model" property is null, even if I do this in the ASPX codebehind that calls the master page:

   ```cs
   public partial class ViewPage : System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Model.Class.Here>
   ```

   As I mentioned above I don't care about the controller or model - is there a way to call HTML.Partial() with a dummy Model, just to get it to generate something?
2. **Render the layout to a string with RazorEngine**

   I haven't been able to figure out how to get RazorEngine to load the existing MVC environment, so it can parse Html commands and expand Bundles etc. - If anyone has any guidance on how to use RazorEngine to just build the layout file from within an MVC project, it would be much appreciated.
3. **WebForm functionality within Razor (somehow)**

   Alternatively if someone can tell me how I can use WebForm style controls which I can read directly and use the AjaxToolkit with inside Razor, I can forget this whole thing.

---

#### Option 1 Code Attempt:

**WebForm Markup (Index.aspx)**:

```xml
<%@ Import Namespace="Bolee.Plugin.CheerRegistration.Models" %>
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="_Razor.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Index.aspx.cs"
Inherits="Views.Admin.ManageWebForm.ViewPage" %>
<!-- NOTE: Views.Admin.ManageWebForm.ViewPage<Models.Webform> here caused an error, so I moved this to the code behind --!>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">Title</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
Content
</asp:Content>
```

**WebForm Code Behind (Index.aspx.cs)**:

```cs
namespace Views.Admin.ManageWebForm
{
    public partial class ViewPage : System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Models.WebForm>
    {

    }
}
```

**Master Markup (_Razor.Master)**:

```xml
<%@ Master Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage" ViewStateMode="Disabled" EnableViewState="false" %>
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" Visible="false"><asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" /></asp:PlaceHolder>
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" Visible="false"><asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"  /></asp:PlaceHolder>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Mvc" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" %>
<%   
    var buildTitle = new StringBuilder();
    var buildMain = new StringBuilder();   
    TitleContent.RenderControl(new HtmlTextWriter(new System.IO.StringWriter(buildTitle)));
    MainContent.RenderControl(new HtmlTextWriter(new System.IO.StringWriter(buildMain)));

    ViewBag.Title = buildTitle.ToString();
    ViewBag.MainContent = buildMain.ToString();
%>
<%=Html.Partial('_Razor.cshtml', viewData: ViewData)%><!-- <- Null Exception error here from "Model" being null -->
```

**CSHTML Markup (_Razor.cshtml)**:

```xml
@model Models.WebForm;

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml";
}

@Html.Raw(ViewBag.MainContent)
```

Comment: You're probably better of maintaining separate master pages and layouts and keeping them in sync manually. That, or choosing *just Web Forms* or *just MVC*.

Comment: @mason It has crossed my mind to do it that way, just really liked the idea of being able to just drop a webform into the MVC project without too much clutter. I appreciate the comment though, thanks!