# Will there be a SSRS reportviewer in ASP.NET 5 MVC 6?

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2015, reportviewer, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working on upgrading an ASP.NET 4.0 WebForms app to MVC6 and cannot find a solution for displaying SSRS reports. With the absents of System.Web the Microsoft ReportViewer control no longer works. What is the best practice for displaying SSRS reports on the web in ASP.NET 5?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Viewing SSRS Reports in an ASP.net MVC Site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4137835/viewing-ssrs-reports-in-an-asp-net-mvc-site)

Answer (score 2):

@Brian - ASP.NET MVC 6 is still in beta stage, its very early to plan for upgrading ASP.NET 4 web forms to MVC 6.

Please try using ASP.NET MVC 5 for upgrading web forms, it (MVC5) will be there for many years to come.

ASP.NET 5 will take good amount of time to mature, so don't hurry.

Comment: Just stay clean of System.Web.*, and you should be OK if you go for MVC5.

Answer (score 1):

There's no direct support for the SSRS in MVC, but there's are common workaround using an iframe. Basically create a webforms project that provides a services to the SSRS reports and inject that into your view.

Have a look at https://github.com/ilich/MvcReportViewer 
I haven't tested it, however its still a glorified wrapper to a webforms iframe in the end. You can find it on NuGet.

There are also paid solutions like Telerik Reports and alike.

Comment: .net 5 doesn't support web form. I was hoping the microsoft team would be introducing way to handle SSRS reportviewer.

Comment: I have asked for feedback regarding updating MvcReportViewer for MVC 6. Have a look: https://github.com/ilich/MvcReportViewer/issues/121
It should be updated in the next couple of months.