# ReportViewer alternatives for ASP.NET MVC

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, reportviewer, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm looking for ReportViewer alternatives that work in the MVC world - a world where I don't have both WebForms and MVC.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33069825/156611) but it still requires WebForms assemblies under the hood and therefore will not work with .NET 5 and MVC 6.

FYI, I'm not tied to SSRS. What I'm looking for is recommendations for other reporting packages that could be a replacement for the SSRS/RDL/ReportViewer trio.

Comment: If you haven't found solution jet. The report control was never updated to work seamlessly with ASP.Net MVC. This [article](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-Display-SSRS-report-e3f6be05) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things you can try.

1.Create SSRS reports and host it on the report server and invoke it as a url in the js.(You can pass the paramters in the querystring itself).You can do this as a seperate project on the webserver and then your mvc app can render the report in HTML iframe or div too.The report will be treated as a seperate website managed by reporting server.

2.Third party tools Telerik has web reports that are compatible with the js frameworks like kendo , angular etc.

https://www.telerik.com/products/reporting.aspx